# How to uninstall redmine plugins?

Tags: redmine, uninstallation, bitbucket

I cannot uninstall the redmine plugin. I typed below as [this redmine page](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/Plugins) describes.

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production
```

And remove the plugin from plugin directory. When redmine restarted, it shows error screen. If I put Redmine Bitbucket back to plugin directory, it works again...

I used [Redmine Bitbucket](http://www.redmine.org/plugins/redmine_bitbucket). The plugin is good. But I wanted to try uninstall it.

Some new redmine plugins have problem like this?

My redmine version is Redmine 2.1.4.stable.

**I solved myself.**

The problem is not on this plugin. I just set my Gemfile.lock's owner as root. I changed the ownership. I can remove this plugin. I will try to use this plugin again.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It's worth noting this:

```
Note: The rake task db:migrate:plugin has been deprecated, please use the replacement version redmine:plugins:migrate
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

```
rake db:migrate:plugin NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: Thanks. I tried rake `redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production` because it's redmine 2.1.4. 

The message is shown: 

> (in /var/lib/redmine)
> Migrating redmine_bitbucket (Redmine Bitbucket plugin)...  

`rake db:migrate:plugin NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production` shows: 

> Note: The rake task db:migrate:plugin has been deprecated, please use the replacement version redmine:plugins:migrate`.

Answer (score 1):

**try this one ..**

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can always see a list of rake tasks that come with your Redmine version.

To see them, just navigate to your redmine root and type:

```
bundle exec rake -T
```

And there when you scroll you will find list of rake tasks associated with plugins, that way you will always use proper uninstall command.