# Cannot uninstall Redmine plugin

Tags: plugins, redmine, uninstallation

I'm using Redmine with redmine_bitbucket plugin, I would like to uninstall that plugin, so what I done was (as redmine system user):

> rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=redmine_bitbucket VERSION=0
> RAILS_ENV=production
>
> Migrating redmine_bitbucket (Redmine Bitbucket plugin)...

However, I still have it on the list of plugins. I tried to remove its directory afterwards, restart apache2 after this command, after removing directory and in virtually every configuration, but it still exists on the list of plugins. In log/production.log after running above command is added only:

```
Connecting to database specified by database.yml
```

I have seen this question [How to uninstall redmine plugins?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14124776/how-to-uninstall-redmine-plugins) but in my case, there isn't problem with ownership of any file as everything is owned by redmine:redmine user.

I'm using `Redmine 2.4.2` and RVM with `ruby 2.0.0p353` on redmine system user.

Any idea how can I debug it further?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove plugins directory and restart redmine.

```
rake redmine:plugins:migrate NAME=plugin_name VERSION=0 RAILS_ENV=production
```

Comment: If I remove plugins directory and run this, I will get "Plugin redmine_bitbucket was not found."

Comment: this plugin [redmine_bitbucket](https://bitbucket.org/steveqx/redmine_bitbucket/src/6808373c6669?at=master) does not have migrations - so you needn't run migration. But it has `Gemfile` - it means that after removing plugin you should run `bundle install RAILS_ENV=production` (options can be another) to clean up `Gemfile.lock` in the core. Restart Redmine. If you still have message  "Plugin redmine_bitbucket was not found." - clarify where exactly you get it, maybe provide aditional information if it is in logs.

Comment: It disappeared after I removed a plugins directory and restarted. Not sure how this works as I tried this before but nonetheless thanks :) .